How to use SPI of a spare stepper driver to connect MAX31865 RTD PT100 or PT1000 Amplifier?
I'm using an Octopus Pro V1.1 controller board with an onboard MAX31865 temperature amplifier for one of the two PT1000 temperature sensors of my Slice Engineering Mosquito Magnum+ hotend.
I want to connect the second temperature sensor using a "MAX31865 RTD PT100 or PT1000 amplifier" board through SPI. How do I connect this amplifier to a spare stepper driver slot so that the second/spare temperature sensor can be read and used in Klipper firmware?

You can re-use a spare stepper slot for a different SPI device, beware of the correct pins to use.
Please read Serial Peripheral Interface for more information.
Note that Serial Data Out (SDO) is used in place of Master-Out Slave-In (MOSI). Serial Data In (SDI) is used in place of Master-In Slave-Out (MISO).
Below is an overview of the pinout of the Stepstick format:

The "MAX31865 RTD PT100 or PT1000 amplifier" is shown below:

Note the corresponding pinout of the amplifier board and the pinout of the stepper slot. Connect the correct pins and configure the pins in Klipper correctly.
